# How is the "how are we doing" survey used?

Tags: discussion, support, short-survey

I just did the "how are we doing" survey and I'm confused as to how are the answers being used. I selected an X amount of problems, hoping to add feedback as to what exactly the problems are, but there was absolutely nothing of the sort on the survey!

Due to the wording, like "system being overly zealous", I think every single option I just chose will be wrongly interpreted. Why? Because the problems I selected are for the opposite reason of what the subtext implied - for example: "Moderation" - I selected it because I think we could do **better** at moderating and we don't close enough $h**, not because "the system is overly zealous". It would be nice if there was a final "submit", as this happened automatically.

Can we have some clarification as to how are those answers being used?

Comment: The last time I took it, which was... maybe 4-6 months ago, I didn't get the same feeling out of the survey. I felt that I was able to provide the answers I intended to with the context I intended, and I'd assume my responses were similar to yours given your concerns.

Comment: @KevinB I remember taking this same survey some time ago (in the last year or so) and having the same idea as yours about it. I don't know what changed or why this time around

Comment: I've taken this survey at least twice and got the same feeling as you. The answering options seemed tailored for "give me the code" people, with the intent of proving how hostile and unwelcoming the community is. At least that's the feeling I got.

Comment: When/how/where was this survey rolled out? I remember seeing one 1 or 2 years ago, but didn't see this last one you are talking about.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I couldn't say, other than the survey says that not everyone is invited (I don't remember the wording, sorry)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto ah that makes sense, I was wondering if I had missed some announcement somewhere.

Comment: Are there any free-form text options in the survey, say, at the end very end? All surveys ought to have it (not just here).

Comment: @PeterMortensen That's what I expected, but it didn't. I skipped all demographic questions, so maybe that affected something?

Comment: well, the survey uses buckets to ensure its getting a response from every "bucket" of users the team wants info from. when a bucket is full, it stops accepting responses from people who fit into that bucket, but the survey doesn't become a different survey based on which bucket you fall into due to the answers (or lack therof) to the demographic questions. (at least, prior versions didn't.)

Answer (score 20):

Unfortunately, I suspect it will mostly be used to justify or increase repressive policing of speech on Stack Exchange sites, because of how "the community is unwelcoming" - as the survey seems engineered to produce that result. See my [related request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415648/please-scrap-the-highly-problematic-how-are-we-doing-survey?noredirect=1&lq=1).

**edit:** perhaps also justify the company's non-responsiveness to key community demands and requests.